# Swiftの付属型enumからデータを取り出すようなコードをHaskellで書きたい

Tags: swift, haskell

[Haskell 代数的データ型 超入門 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/7shi/items/1ce76bde464b4a55c143) で Haskellのデータ型はEnumのようであるというような記述を見かけました。サンプルに載っている

> data Color = Blue | Red | Green | White

は Swiftで書くと

```
enum Color {
    case blue
    case red
    case green
    case white
}
```

こんな感じでしょう。

さて Swift では [付属型enum(Associated Value)](https://qiita.com/hachinobu/items/392c96820588d1c03b0c#%E4%BB%98%E5%B1%9E%E5%9E%8Benumassociated-value) が使えますから、Enumのパワーが強力です。おそらくHaskellにだいぶ近いんじゃないでしょうか？

上記リンクにある

> ```
> enum Barcode {
>     case upca(Int, Int, Int, Int)
>     case qrcode(String)
> }
> ```

を使って下記のようなSwiftコードを書いてみました

```
import Foundation
enum Barcode {
    case upca(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case qrcode(String)
}
func getBarcodeString(barcode: Barcode) -> String {
    switch barcode {
    case .upca(let a, let b, let c, let d):
        return String(a) + String(b) + String(c) + String(d)
    case .qrcode(let s):
        return s
    }
}
let barcode1 = Barcode.upca(1, 2, 3, 4)
let barcode2 = Barcode.qrcode("A")
print(getBarcodeString(barcode: barcode1))
print(getBarcodeString(barcode: barcode2))
```

出力結果は

```
1234
A
```

です。

これと同じことをHaskellでやってみようと思ったのですが、関数を書くのに慣れておらずうまく書けません。型と変数だけはうまく作れたので下記に載せます。

```
data Barcode = Upca Int Int Int Int
             | Qrcode String
             
barcode1 = Upca 1 2 3 4
barcode2 = Qrcode "A"
```

`getBarcodeString` は Haskellだとどう書けばいいんでしょうか？

おそらく Swift の `case .upca(let a, let b, let c, let d):` みたいな取り出し方はHaskellになくて、[こちらで質問した](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69956/%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e5%9e%8b%e3%81%ae1%e7%95%aa%e7%9b%ae%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b) ときのサンプルに載っている全件取り出しみたいな関数を別途作らないといけないのかな？（とはいえそれらのパーツをうまくつないで1つの関数を作る方法がわかっていません）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

引数部分にパターンを使えるので次のように書けます。

```
getBarcodeString :: Barcode -> String
getBarcodeString (Upca a b c d) = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d
getBarcodeString (Qrcode s    ) = s

main = do
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode1
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode2
```

より素朴に`case`式を使うのであれば

```
getBarcodeString' :: Barcode -> String
getBarcodeString' x = case x of
    Upca a b c d -> show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d
    Qrcode s     -> s
```

となります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回の質問に対してはこれでいいと思うのですが、実際に試してみて別途質問が出ましたので、念の為記載しておきます。[swift - 実行時に Non-exhaustive patterns in case エラー になるので、実装漏れに気づけない - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69970/%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-case-%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7-%e5%ae%9f%e8%a3%85%e6%bc%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%ab%e6%b0%97%e3%81%a5%e3%81%91%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)