# 実行時に Non-exhaustive patterns in case エラー になるので、実装漏れに気づけない

Tags: swift, haskell

[Swiftの付属型enumからデータを取り出すようなコードをHaskellで書きたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69968/swift%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%98%e5%b1%9e%e5%9e%8benum%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e5%87%ba%e3%81%99%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%82%92haskell%e3%81%a7%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)で付属型enumと同じようにHaskellを書くにはどうすればいいかと聞きました。

確かに Swiftコード

```
import Foundation
enum Barcode {
    case upca(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case qrcode(String)
}
func getBarcodeString(barcode: Barcode) -> String {
    switch barcode {
    case .upca(let a, let b, let c, let d):
        return String(a) + String(b) + String(c) + String(d)
    case .qrcode(let s):
        return s
    }
}
let barcode1 = Barcode.upca(1, 2, 3, 4)
let barcode2 = Barcode.qrcode("A")
print(getBarcodeString(barcode: barcode1))
print(getBarcodeString(barcode: barcode2))
```

は

```
data Barcode = Upca Int Int Int Int
             | Qrcode String
             
barcode1 = Upca 1 2 3 4
barcode2 = Qrcode "A"

getBarcodeString :: Barcode -> String
getBarcodeString x = case x of
    Upca a b c d -> show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d
    Qrcode s     -> s

main = do
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode1
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode2
```

と同じと思ったのですが、上記コードから case内の`Qrcode s     -> s` の部分を抜いて下記のようにしてみました。

```
data Barcode = Upca Int Int Int Int
             | Qrcode String
             
barcode1 = Upca 1 2 3 4
barcode2 = Qrcode "A"

getBarcodeString :: Barcode -> String
getBarcodeString x = case x of
    Upca a b c d -> show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d

main = do
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode1
    putStrLn $ getBarcodeString barcode2
```

これをコンパイルして実行

まずコンパイル:

```
% docker run -it --rm --name bar-haskell -v "$PWD":/tmp -w /tmp haskell:8 ghc -o Bar Bar.hs
```

そして実行:

```
% docker run -it --rm --name bar-haskell -v "$PWD":/tmp -w /tmp haskell:8 ./Bar
1234
Bar: Bar.hs:(8,22)-(9,56): Non-exhaustive patterns in case
```

`1234`が表示されたあとで、 `Non-exhaustive patterns in case` が出ています。
Swiftであれば switch にすべてのパターンを網羅しないとコンパイルエラーになるので、実装漏れを防げるのですが、Haskellで同様に実装漏れに気づく方法はありますか？

Comment: Swift の話は本筋と関係ないのと，「念の為関数版も…」以降は実質重複なので，ないほうが質問として読みやすいかなと少し思いました．

Comment: そうですね。思い切って消しましょう（消しました）。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC のオプションに [`-Wincomplete-patterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns) があるのでこれを使ってみてください．

```
$ ghc -Wincomplete-patterns  a.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )

a.hs:7:22: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a case alternative: Patterns not matched: (Qrcode _)
  |
7 | getBarcodeString x = case x of
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^...
Linking a ...
```

コンパイルエラーにしたい場合は，`-Werror=⟨wflag⟩` を使えそうです．

```
$ ghc -Werror=incomplete-patterns  a.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )

a.hs:7:22: error: [-Wincomplete-patterns, -Werror=incomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a case alternative: Patterns not matched: (Qrcode _)
  |
7 | getBarcodeString x = case x of
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^...
```

Comment: なるほど。コンパイルエラーではないですが、警告になるわけですね。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi 調べてみるとコンパイルエラーにすることもできるようなので追記しました（すみません）．